# want to Highlighting the rows if enter M in arrowed cell in excel

Tags: excel

Highlighting the rows if enter M in arrowed cell in excel

[image: 1]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use conditional formatting.

In that cell (say it's `I2`), set up a new rule with a custom formula:

```
=IF($B2="M")
```

Then format the cell to be Green.

Comment: Thax you so much