# Want to highlight the row using left function if I entered 'V' in arrowed textbox

Tags: excel

[image: highlighting rows if I enter s in arrowed textbox]

highlighting rows if I enter s in arrowed textbox

Comment: try conditional formatting

Comment: Didn't you ask this question several hours ago?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [want to Highlighting the rows if enter M in arrowed cell in excel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52780555/want-to-highlighting-the-rows-if-enter-m-in-arrowed-cell-in-excel)

Comment: It may be helpful to decide if you want to do the formatting based on “V” as per the question title or the “s” as per the body of your question....

Answer (score 0):

Use conditional formatting based on the following formula.

```
=left($a2)="V"
'combined with your previous question
=and(left($a2)=$h$5, $b2=$h$3)
```